# Blend WPF project does not show intellisense for Colors 

Tags: wpf, silverlight, expression-blend, blend, expression-blend-4

Hi this is a very 'beginner' question. I am doing a tutorial with Expression Blend, it is a Silverlight tutorial but I am trying to follow along in a new WPF project. I cannot seem to get the intellisense to work when I type 'colors' in the following line:

```
Me.myRectangle.Fill = New SolidColorBrush(Colors.Beige)
```

As soon as I type the dot at the end of Colors I get no intellisense. Even if I type System.Windows.Media.Colors. , it still offers no help. Even if I put

```
Imports System.Windows.Media
```

at the top there is no difference.

If I do this in Visual Studio it works fine, and I get prompting for which color I want.

Am I expecting too much of Blend? The tutorial I am following (Silverlight in C#) shows it working normally, so why would it not work for WPF VB?

All I did in the beginning was create a new project (in Blend, Visual Basic language, Framework Version 4.0), then put down a rectangle and a button. I selected the button, then Properties -> Events and double clicked 'Click' to create the event in the code-behind.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: I would imagine Blend has some issue with producing the IntelliSense for VB.NET in some areas. Have you made sure your version of Blend is fully up to date?

Comment: I can't say for sure how it should work because I refuse to write code in Blend, just like I refuse to design XAML in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I discovered that the Intellisense wasn't working because, like any other normal person, I was typing "color" in lower case and for whatever reason in Blend 4, lower case does not trigger the Intellisense engine. It was only when I started capitalizing 'Color' that it worked normally. ????
I wonder why the weird divergence from Visual Studio 2010?